# How to mock an object at instantiation?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm new to JUnit testing. I'd like to put mock my own variable during a test when a specific instantiation occurs.

```
Map<Integer, JsMenuItem> menuItemsMap = new HashMap<Integer, JsMenuItem>();
```

I'd like to do something like this in my `Test`:

```
Map<Integer, JsMenuItem> menuItemsMapMock = new HashMap<Integer, JsMenuItem>();
Mockito.when("new HashMap<Integer, JsMenuItem>()").thenReturn(menuItemsMapMock);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by mocking the class field menuItemsMap? I suspect what you're trying to accomplish can be done entirely without mocks. You should normally only mock objects between module boundaries.

Comment: If your map is instanciated within the method you want to test, then I'm afraid you won't be able to mock it. In this case you should refactor your code to make it more testable: splitting big methods into smaller ones : this way, the methods that hold the business code could take the map as parameter, and be easily testable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should delagate the Map initialization to a public method and then mock the method result.